# How to change properties of wav file while uploading to server using multer nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, wav, multer

Here is my code

**Front-end  (index.js)**

```
var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type': 'audio/wav' });
chunks = [];
var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], 'c4_1.wav');
var url1 = URL.createObjectURL(fileOfBlob);
player.src = url;

console.log(blob);

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('up1', blob, 'c4_1.wav');
fetch('/testblob', {
    method: 'post',
    body: fd
});
```

**Server side (server.js)**

```
var upload1 = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, __dirname + "/public/uploads/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "c4_1" + Date.now()+ ".wav");
        // callback(null, "c4_1.wav");
    }
});

var type = multer({
    storage: upload1
    // }).array("imgUploader", 1,); //Field name and max count
}).any(); //Field name and max count

app.post("/testblob", type, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
})
```

And the properties of the file is like [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuMDI.png)

But i want something like this : [Please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOGOe.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: I had solved this using multer on server side and sending BLOB object using libraries itself